# PHPMyAdmin blank page but HTML source is present

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I just installed Nginx 1.6.0, MySQL, PHP-FPM 5.5.9 and phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit server. When I go to domain.tld/phpmyadmin I end up at a blank page but when I view source, I can see the HTML login forms, javascripts and everything else, although the page is blank.

I've followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04) and normal PHP scripts work. A simple PHP script that echoes "hello" works perfectly fine. There are no errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log or access.log.
Here's my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 8081 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

Just tell me if you need more information. As stated, the error.log is blank.

Comment: Exactly what appears in the HTML source?

Comment: There's a lot, but no errors. I see the  login form.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't see it!

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML head inexplicably contains the following:

```
<style>html{display: none;}</style>
```

This does exactly what you think it does: it turns off display for the entire document.

If you didn't put that in there, seek help from whoever did.

Comment: Odd, this is a fresh installation made a few minutes ago.

Comment: @TomJordell did you ever find a solution to this? confirmed that this is happening on my fresh installations of phpmyadmin. driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; changing the `$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming']` in config fixed the problem. It is was to js disabled on browser. See https://github.com/zixtor/phpmyadmin/commit/c1e8834e44f110aca736e49a6def3e4c11015879